# Method returns true even though it should not. Possible complication with for loop

Tags: java, boolean

I'm quite new to Java so please bear with me. I wrote this program:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int[] list = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10};
    isUnique(list);
    System.out.println(isUnique(list));

}

private static boolean isUnique(int[] array) 
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int n : array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (n == array[i])
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (count > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

It's supposed to check the array and see, if there are any more than 1 of each number. However it doesn't seem to work. It returns true even if there are two 1's. Any ideas? I suspect the for loop isn't working, but I'm not quite sure why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the issue become more apparent if you rewrite the second conditional equivalently as `return count <= 1;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns `true` no matter what because you have that `else` block.  Because `count` starts up zero and it increases a maximum of one time per loop, that `else` block will **always** run (if the array length is not 0).  You can think of this as two cases:

Case 1. `n == array[i]` --> count will equal 1 -->  `count>1` is **not** true --> else block runs and returns true.

Case 2. n is not `array[i]` --> count equals 0 --> count`>1` is **not** true --> else block runs and returns true

Comment: @AndyTurner nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns true after checking the first element, since after checking the first element `count == 1`, so your else statement is executed :

```
        if (count > 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            return true;
        }
```

You should only return `true` after checking all the elements in your array and finding no duplicates.

If the input array is sorted, you don't need a nested loop to determine if there are two consecutive equal numbers. A single loop will do.

If the array is not sorted, you'll have to maintain a count for the number of occurrences of each value found in the array, for which purpose a `HashMap` can be used.

Assuming sorted input array :

```
private static boolean isUnique(int[] array) 
{
    if (array.length <= 1)
        return true;

    int previous = array[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (previous == array[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
        previous = array[i];
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry hah, I couldn't quite follow your solution at the end. I am quite new to the point where everything is a mystery to me. Would you mind explaining it? Please :D

Comment: @javanewbie The loop compares in each iteration the previous element to the current element. If you find two consecutive equal elements, you return false. If you reach the end of the loop without returning false, this means all the elements are unique (assuming the array is sorted), so you return true.

Comment: But doesn't it only check the first number (in this case 1)? Doesn't look like the previous increments? :P

Comment: Hah sorry, never mind. I got it, thanks for your help :) And thanks everyone else as well!

Comment: Well actually ... It doesn't seem to check if array[0] appears in the other indexes?

Comment: @javanewbie It does. `previous` is initialized to `array[0]`, so in the first iteration of the loop, when `previous` is compared to `array[1]`, we check whether `array[0]==array[1]`.

Comment: Yes, but if I include an extra 1 at the end of the array it still returns true.

Comment: @javanewbie I did write that my code assumes the array is sorted. If that's not the case, you can use a HashSet to keep track of the unique numbers you encounter, and return false if you encounter a number already in the HashSet.